# using Reinforcement learning for binary classification

Tags: reinforcement-learning, optimization, keras-rl, binary-classification

I want to build an agent for binary classification. I have a large dataset with two label (0 and 1). I want to build an agent to predict labels. I build a deep model and now I want to build an agent. I use keras-rl2. but there is a problem: for dqn agent, the fit function has an env argument. I don't know how can I define my problem environment for that.
note that my problem has a similarity function that optimize weights for each feature. the agent can also select the best weight for each feature. but the problem is that I don't know how can I define my environment.

Comment: This sounds like the standard setup for supervised learning, not reinforcement learning.

Comment: There is not usually a good reason to apply reinforcement learning to a supervised learning problem. It will be slower to train, and is likely to produce a model that is less accurate at the end. *Sometimes* there are reasons why it is worthwhile. Could you clarify why you want to apply reinforcement learning in your case?

Comment: I have an agent that each time sees an instance, it should select an instance in memory that has the most similarity with that. I just want to train the agent to select the best instance. @NeilSlater

Comment: That doesn't seem like a reinforcement learning problem. Unless there is a consequence to the agent's situation other than being right or wrong, then there is normally no reason to use RL fo rthis kind of identification or classification task.